# OnClickListener only increments one time

Tags: android, button, increment, onclicklistener

I'm trying to have a page with a bunch of buttons, each of which increments its own variable. When I click on a button the first time, the variable is incremented no problem. However, the second time, the value is not incremented. I have all the listeners contained within one `onclicklistener handler`, which could be part of the problem, but I don't want to rewrite all my code if that won't fix it, or if there's an easier fix.
Code:

```
final OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener()
    {           
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Squad current = new Squad(BasketballGUIActivity.currentsquad);
            if (v == us2)
            {
                current.usTotal2++;
                us2.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(us2);
                Log.e("ustotal2", ""+current.usTotal2);
                return;
            }
            if(v==us2made)
            {
                current.usTotal2made+=1;
                us2made.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(us2made); 
            }
            if(v==them2)
            {
                current.themTotal2+=1;  
                them2.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(them2);   
            }
            if(v==them2made)
            {
                current.themTotal2made+=1;
                them2made.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(them2made);   
            }
            if(v==us1)
            {
                current.usTotal1+=1;
                us1.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(us1); 
            }
            if(v==us1made)
            {
                current.usTotal1made+=1;
                us1made.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(us1made); 
            }
            if(v==them1)
            {
                current.themTotal1+=1;
                them1.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(them1);   
            }
            if(v==them1made)
            {
                current.themTotal1made+=1;
                them1made.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(them1made);   
            }
            if(v==us0reb)
            {
                current.usTotalOreb+=1;
                us0reb.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(us0reb);  
            }
            if(v==usxreb)
            {
                current.usTotalXreb+=1;
                usxreb.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(usxreb);  
            }
            if(v==them0reb)
            {
                current.themTotalOreb+=1;
                them0reb.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(them0reb);    
            }
            if(v==themxreb)
            {
                current.themTotalXreb+=1;
                themxreb.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(themxreb);    
            }
            if(v==us3)
            {
                current.usTotal3+=1;
                us3.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(us3); 
            }
            if(v==us3made)
            {
                current.usTotal3made+=1;
                us3made.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(us3made); 
            }
            if(v==them3)
            {
                current.themTotal3+=1;
                them3.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(them3);   
            }
            if(v==them3made)
            {
                current.themTotal3made+=1;
                them3made.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(them3made);   
            }
            if(v==us2foul)
            {
                current.usTotal2foul+=1;
                us2foul.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(us2foul); 
            }
            if(v==us2foulmade)
            {
                current.usTotal2foulmade+=1;
                us2foulmade.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(us2foulmade); 
            }
            if(v==us3foul)
            {
                current.usTotal3foul+=1;
                us3foul.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(us3foul); 
            }
            if(v==us3foulmade)
            {
                current.usTotal3foulmade+=1;
                us3foulmade.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(us3foulmade); 
            }
            if(v==usTO)
            {
                current.usTotalTO+=1;
                usTO.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(usTO);    
            }
            if(v==them2foul)
            {
                current.themTotal2foul+=1;
                them2foul.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(them2foul);   
            }
            if(v==them2foulmade)
            {
                current.themTotal2foulmade+=1;
                them2foulmade.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(them2foulmade);   
            }
            if(v==them3foul)
            {
                current.themTotal3foul+=1;
                them3foul.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(them3foul);   
            }
            if(v==them3foulmade)
            {
                current.themTotal3foulmade+=1;
                them3foulmade.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(them3foulmade);   
            }
            if(v==themTO)
            {
                current.themTotalTO+=1;
                themTO.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                new ButtonColorTask().execute(themTO);  
            }
}
```

And for the sake of space, yes I initialize all the buttons to the listener (and if I did not, they wouldn't even increment a first time). I'm wondering what's going wrong, and if there's an easy way to fix this. I think the problem could be that I don't have a separate listener for each button, but I'm not sure.
To recap, the problem is that when I click a button, my variable is incremented once, but never more than once. Strangely enough though, each additional button press will in fact run the `ButtonColorTask` (which is just changing the color of the buttons back to default after a certain amount of time), which really just confuses me more. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: each time you create a new Squad current = new Squad(BasketballGUIActivity.currentsquad);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move Squad current = new Squad(BasketballGUIActivity.currentsquad); into class member level.

```
final OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener()
    {           
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Squad current = new Squad(BasketballGUIActivity.currentsquad);
------>
final OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener()
    {   
        Squad current = new Squad(BasketballGUIActivity.currentsquad);        
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
```

Comment: without using "if (v == us2)", use "switch(v.getId()){case R.id.BUTTONID:}" good for performance.

Comment: Oh geez..... thanks for that. As it always is, the answer was way too simple for me to find

Answer (score 0):

The way you are checking the click of a particular button is wrong. It should as follows:

```
 if(v.getId() == R.id.BUTTONID) {
```

}

Do the same for all the other buttons. I suppose this (along with taking the variable `current` out of the `onClick()`) should solve your problem.